# Is there any difference in meaning between "do you follow me?" and "are you following me?" when are you asking someone if they understand you?

Tags: present-continuous, present-simple

Can you please tell me if there is there any difference in meaning between *do you follow me?* and *are you following me?* when you asking someone if they understand you? For example:

I've heard both used in that sense, but I haven't been able to figure out if there is any difference in meaning. Is there any?

I ask because very often there is a small difference between the present continuous and present simple.

Comment: There is no difference in meaning. Why would you think there was?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Because very often there is a small difference between the present continuous and present simple.

Comment: I think **do you follow me** indicates a permanent situation, on the other hand **Are you following me** indicates a current situation.

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference in meaning between "do you follow me?" and "are you following me?"

Since "are you following me" is continuous, it suggests that you will continue the learning activity after you answer the question. But the meaning is the same.